# Plotting smooth functions from my GAM in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, gam

I have created a GAM and set up the predictions but having trouble with how to plot any smooth functions from my model. Been trying to plot these in ggplot but having trouble with the arguments/aesthetics now I have added in a the month aswell, seening some people say to use geom_smooth() too but I'm not sure. If anyone can advise me on this that would be great, i had added my data, model and predictions below;

model

```
mod = gam(co2 ~ s(timeStep, k = 200, bs = "cs") + s(month, k = 12, bs = "cc"), 
                data = carbonD,
                family = gaussian(link = "identity"))
```

predictions

```
#create predictions
preds = predict(mod, type = 'terms', se.fit = TRUE) 
#combine our predictions with coefficients
fit = preds$fit + coef(mod)[1]
```

data snipet

```
carbonD
       co2 month year timeStep
1   315.42     1 1959        1
2   316.31     2 1959        2
3   316.50     3 1959        3
4   317.56     4 1959        4
5   318.13     5 1959        5
6   318.00     6 1959        6
7   316.39     7 1959        7
8   314.65     8 1959        8
9   313.68     9 1959        9
10  313.18    10 1959       10
11  314.66    11 1959       11
12  315.43    12 1959       12
13  316.27     1 1960       13
14  316.81     2 1960       14
15  317.42     3 1960       15
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to plot your exact model in ggplot. One is to use `geom_smooth`, but you can't do this with two variables on the right hand side. Actually, in your case it would be possible because month is calculable from the time step, but let's ignore that for now and just plot your model predictions directly using a ribbon and a line.

First, load the required packages and create the model (note because we only have a snippet of your data, I have had to reduce the number of knots)

```r
library(mgcv)
library(ggplot2)

mod = gam(co2 ~ s(timeStep, k = 4, bs = "cs") + s(month, k = 12, bs = "cc"), 
                data = carbonD,
                family = gaussian(link = "identity"))
```

Now we create a little data frame of the values we want our predictions at, with 1000 points across the range of our data:

```r
newdata <- data.frame(timeStep = seq(1, 15, length.out = 1000),
                      month = (seq(1, 15, length.out = 1000) - 1) %% 12 + 1)
```

Now we make our predictions and use the standard error fit to create an upper and lower  confidence band.

```r
pred <- predict(mod, newdata, type = 'response', se.fit = TRUE) 

newdata$co2   <- pred$fit
newdata$lower <- pred$fit - 1.96 * pred$se.fit
newdata$upper <- pred$fit + 1.96 * pred$se.fit
```

Now we can plot our results:

```r
ggplot(carbonD, aes(timeStep, co2)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_ribbon(data = newdata, alpha = 0.3,
              aes(ymin = lower, ymax = upper, fill = "confidence interval")) +
  geom_line(data = newdata, aes(color = "GAM")) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = "lightblue", name = NULL) +
  scale_color_manual(values = "darkblue", name = NULL) +
  theme_minimal(base_size = 16)
```

[image]

It is also possible to use your gam within `geom_smooth` directly, but you need to be able to express the model in terms of `y` and `x`, where `x` is the time step. You can get the month by subtracting 1 from the time step, getting this number modulo 12, and adding 1 again, so it is possible to avoid explicitly creating a prediction data frame, at the cost of making the plotting code more complex:

```r
ggplot(carbonD, aes(timeStep, co2)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(formula = y ~ s(x, k = 4, bs = "cs") + 
                            s((x - 1) %% 12 + 1, k = 12, bs = "cc"),
              method = "gam", size = 0.7,
              method.args = list(family = gaussian(link = "identity")),
              aes(color = "gam", fill = "confidence interval")) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = "lightblue", name = NULL) +
  scale_color_manual(values = "darkblue", name = NULL) +
  theme_minimal(base_size = 16)
```

[image]

As a caveat to this, it is not clear to me that you should have both month and timestep, since one is just the modulus of the other. It may be better to use just timestep alone, or use *year* and month if you want to separate the long-term and seasonal effects.

Comment: Perfect, got mine plotting now. Yeh Ideally both the smooth functions for timestep and month so test for seasonal effects. Lastly, do you know the aesthetics changes I'd need to make for the type = 'terms' argument as it's slighly different with 2 smooth functions? (just trying out a few things)

Comment: @Joe I don't think you can use the "terms" type if you want to see the model predictions on the same scale as the original data.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way would be to use `geom_smooth` with LOESS: `geom_smooth(method="loess", span=0.5)` and play with the `span` parameter to get a more smooth or wiggly shape.

Comment: This is true, but doesn't plot the actual gam model the OP wanted.